# How to remove time part from a datetime in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

If I've got a Kusto `datetime` and I want to remove the time portion, leaving just a date at midnight, what's the best way? I can do this

```
todatetime(format_datetime( now(), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

but surely there's a more efficient way?

Comment: Your question is confusing because you first stated that you want to remove the time part entirely (as shown in your code example), but then you indicated that you want "at midnight", which is a time part.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the [`startofday()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startofdayfunction) function:

```
startofday( now() )
```

or the [`bin()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction) function:

```
bin( now(), 1d )
```